# Is there value in maintaining my TDD tests when requirements change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I've been using TDD for a while now and it works well most of the time. From my understanding, I write the test (red) and work the code (green).  This serves as a great tool to focus on coding just what is required.

The application I'm currently working on has fairly loose user requirements to say the least!  This can create the need to change the existing code base in trivial manner all the way up to redesigning full sections.

When I do this a lot of my tests fail ... understandably since the design has changed. What should I do with these old tests?  I'm finding maintaining them can become an issue.

I suppose the core of my question is:

Is TDD used more to create a coding "map" to help focus you as a developer to write code and then some other testing paradigm is used in conjunction to ensure that everything "works" when the code is handed off? Or, do people use TDD as a full-stop-shop that can both help create cleaner code AND work as a full test suite, hence I'll need to maintain my full test suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests written while doing TDD absolutely are valuable throughout the lifetime of an application.

The purpose of TDD is to allow you to build up your code test by test, so that it always meets the requirements you've implemented thus far (this is the "works" part), is fully tested and is well factored. When you're done you'll have a full regression test suite as a bonus, which is valuable. So for both proving what requirements you've implemented and for regression, it's valuable to keep your tests running.

If requirements change so fast that you can't maintain the test suite, you have a project management problem. Explain to your customers that you don't have enough time to ensure quality, or that they need to hire a test engineer.

Comment: Thanks for that, makes sense and is pretty much how I imagined it.